# Qual è il significato di "lapsus"?

Tags: word-meaning

Ciao a tutti,
so che con "lapsus" si intende comunemente un errore di distrazione oppure la dimenticanza di una parola durante un discorso.

Ho conoscenti però che lo usano più in generale ad intendere "dimenticanza" (di avvenimenti o fatti vari): è corretto questo uso?

Grazie in anticipo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sembra che questo uso sia comune.

Da Treccani.it, ***[lapsus](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/lapsus/):***

> In senso più ampio, il termine è spesso usato in tono scherzoso o ironico per giustificare un errore, soprattutto scritto, attribuendolo a distrazione e a un atto involontario: è stato un lapsus!
>
> Meno comune la locuzione  *lapsus memoriae*, improvvisa dimenticanza, momentaneo difetto della memoria.

Comment: Dunque l'uso è valido in un contesto principalmente ironico, capisco. Magari non avevo carpito l'ironia dell'affermazione.
Grazie